# Repeated "link-only" answers

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers, duplicate-answers

Check these link-only, and duplicate answers by the same author.

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9546568/2006333), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9858395/2006333), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9549001/2006333), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9547159/2006333), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9547138/2006333), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9547087/2006333), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9546898/2006333), [8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9546795/2006333), [9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9546738/2006333), [10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9546506/2006333), [11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9858395/2006333)...

All these answers appeared on the low-quality posts review list repeatedly, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10686631).

Are these questions duplicates? Or only answers?

How can we avoid this?

Comment: Well they're all from 2012 so I wouldn't freak out too much.

Comment: OK. Now most of them are deleted I think...

Comment: I've already flagged as *in need of moderator intervention* before see your meta post...

Comment: @KevinGuan please write an answer

Comment: Usually, the _correct_ course of action is to flag it with a custom reason explaining the situation. You don't need to bring this to meta.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: I'd much rather users get their clarification on meta than post us flags when in doubt. Flags aren't intended for getting feedback from moderators - while we *can* reply to flags while handling them, users aren't notified in any discoverable way other than a very well-hidden link (or in the case of declined flags, the next time they click flag).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've already flagged the posts as *In need of moderator intervention*, and it's helpful now. Also the answers have been deleted.

[image: My flag]